# Drupal Reuse module

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I'm new at Drupal, however I have been studying module development and I managed to complete some functionallity using blocks and jQuery. But the requirements got bigger, and in some part the user wants to upload and image, and crop it to create a thumbnail that will be presented in other block. 
I know that this exact behaviour is already done in some community modules, specifically ImageFieldCrop, so I would like to use that... however I would like to save the uploaded image and the cropped one, in a folder inside my custom module. So the question is? How could I extend that module?... is it necessary to rewrite the code in order to point the correct path??? Or is there a way to intercept hook methods?. Since I'm new at drupal development I apologize if this sounds like a basic question... anyway it would be great if anyone can provide me some links or tutorials showing how to intercept hooks or use other module code on the ones I create. Thanks a lot

Comment: It solely depends on the module that you want to extend, if the module contributor has provided facility to intercept hooks, yes that is best option, else need to re-write the code - no other option.

Comment: As far as I recall, modules are not allowed to create files in the directory containing modules; that is with the default file permissions used by Drupal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to allow users to upload images and files, this is probably best achieved using a 'filefield', which in D7 became part of its core module set.  When you add and configure the field (as part of the content type creation process) you have the chance to set the path that you'd like files to be saved to.

**JS Cropping and Image Styles**

In terms of crop solutions, I can recommend the [EPSA Crop](http://drupal.org/project/epsacrop) module.  This allows your user to define a number different crop areas for each uploaded image, and do so using an interactive JS widget.  It works in conventions with D7's 'image styles' (formally imagecache in D6) which allows for efficient reuse and manipulations of images; e.g. your user uploads one high res image and variations can be created for use in various places around your site.

Once your styles have been created, you can add them programmatically using an API theme call ([theme_image_style](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/theme_image_style/7))

**Avoid Ignoring Established Conventions**

However, Drupal as a system sets a number of conventions, which should ideally be followed.

In terms of user-originated files, it's best to store these in your site's files directory.  Drupal makes use of two types of file access - public, which doesn't look after any kind of access permissions and private - which allows for access restrictions to be able applied.  By choosing to store files in your modules directory, you're likely to cause problems for yourself or any furture developer.

I'd recommend against saving these files in your modules directory, unless you have a *very* good reason for doing so.